# Delphi 7 Indy 10 ioHandler

Tags: delphi, irc, indy10

Trying to make a simple IRC client for personal use so I installed Delphi 7 and Indy 10, note that I haven't done any work in delphi for 10 (?) years and even then it wasn't that advanced. Just for playing around.

```
procedure TForm1.IRCPrivateMessage(ASender: TIdContext; const ANickname,
  AHost, ATarget, AMessage: String);
begin
  if ATarget = '#channel' then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('[' + TimeToStr(Time) + '] <' + ANickname + '> ' + Amessage);
  end;
  if ATarget = '#channel2' then
  begin
    Memo2.Lines.Add('[' + TimeToStr(Time) + '] <' + ANickname + '> ' + Amessage);
  end;
end;
```

This will freeze the program because of two uses of Amessage?

Would be great if anyone could show me a working example of getting time, nick and message added to a memo on the privatemessage event :)

Comment: Nothing in that code obviously lads to a crash. And please define crash. You need to learn to make such reports more precise. Try making an SSCCE.

Comment: updated the code a bit

Comment: So what is the error? You've now got different code, and instead of a crash you now have a freeze. Please be precise. Make an SSCCE. -1

Comment: IRCPrivateMessage runs in the separate thread <> GUI thread. Accessing the GUI via Memo1 is not allowed. You need to synchronize. See [`(Delphi 2009) idIRC, MDI, and problems with hanging`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1734757/576719).

Comment: Aha, will look in to that! thanks LU RD!

Comment: Take a ready sources and modify them as you need or take needed parts of it: VisualIRC,  Delphi-7 written chat, http://sourceforge.net/p/visualirc/mercurial/ci/default/tree/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the answer to the question [`(Delphi 2009) idIRC, MDI, and problems with hanging`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1734757/576719), `IRCPrivateMessage` runs in the same thread as the blocking socket. Accessing the GUI from this event handler without proper protection is not allowed.

You need to use `Synchronize`, `Queue` or other techniques like posting messages to the main thread.